# Rigorous books that develop euclidean geometry

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

I am looking for rigorous English-language books that develop Euclidean geometry. I know Euclid's Elements is not rigorous by modern standards, because he neglected topics like betweenness. And Hilbert's book on geometry is in German. I would be very grateful for a list of such books.

Comment: Hilbert's book has been translated, [here](https://smile.amazon.com/Foundations-Geometry-David-Hilbert/dp/0469306068/ref=tmm_hrd_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1625343170&sr=8-1).  Or there's [Hartshorne](https://smile.amazon.com/Geometry-Euclid-Beyond-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387986502/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=hartshorne+geometry&qid=1625343206&sr=8-2)

Comment: Introduction To Geometry by Coxeter, especially the chapter Ordered Geometry.

Comment: You can get Hilbert's book in English for free here: https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/17384

Comment: Hi user107952. I've just written an answer to a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197862/a-book-that-constructs-analytic-geometry-from-synthetic-geometry/4231362#4231362). These are books that develop geometry rigorously, but they're not really an exploration of the foundations of geometry if that's what you want. For that, Hartshorne's book is good, **but** it expends a ton of effort on looking at what happens when you weaken the continuity axioms, which isn't everyone's cup of tea. I found Pogorelov's *Lectures on the Foundations of Geometry* to be great, and

Comment: you get to interesting stuff (like hyperbolic geometry) much faster. It makes for much better reading than Hilbert too. (I've just realized that you said "in English", so that eliminates what I wrote in my other answer from contention.)